# How ISP has access to backbone?

Tags: domains, isp

I am computer science student. I normal do traceroute host on my linux machine. To find out which hosting service the website uses. When i track the locations of the traceroute it is like.

- INDIA IP
- INDIA IP
- USA IP
- USA IP

how is it that Indian ip and then usa, satellites ?? then why aren't satellite ips not getting displayed ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about **[webmastering as defined in the FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: Help me migrate the question to server fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single internet backbone. The internet consists of thousands of independent networks that are connected in various places. Some of these networks just handle their own traffic, but some offer their connectivity to others. Some are even specifically built to carry traffic, usually for a price. Bigger networks can span continents with fibre optic cable, and smaller networks usually buy connectivity to far-away networks from such big transit networks.

Lets take one of the networks I helped build and design. It is connected to two internet exchanges where it connects (peers) directly with other networks. If I have packets for their network I send them directly to their routers over the internet exchange and vice versa. It is also connected to multiple transits that offer connectivity to the rest of the world.

PS: mapping IP adresses to geographical locations correctly is hard. They don't belong to a location, they are assigned to an organisation that runs a network, and that network can span many countries and even continents.